# @ in python code with minted

Tags: minted, python

I want to add some python code using the minted package to my latex file. I used

```
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}
A @ B
\end{minted}
```

which worked until  now that I have some @ in my code (I am new here and don't know how to add the compiled version). The @ will display with a red box around them. Does someone know how to get rid of this red box?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Take a screenshot of the PDF and paste into your answer (or click the button to add images) to show output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python` lexer thinks the syntax `A @ B` is an error. Instead you can use the `python3` lexer, which does accept it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
%%% python3 instead of python
{python3}
A @ B
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The comment `%%% python3 instead of python` generates an error: `! FancyVerb Error: Extraneous input "%%% python3 instead of python" between \begin{minted}[<key=value>] and line end` I had to delete it ito successfully complete the compilation.

Comment: Ah yes, I added that after I compiled myself :) it was intended as extra clarification. If the comment is above the line then it works fine, I edited my answer.

Comment: Indeed, there it compiles.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

One more solution I found is to change the style of minted to something that does not show errors. Go to https://pygments.org/demo/#try and try the different styles for the code. The style "xcode" for example would work in this case. Then just type

```
\usemintedstyle{xcode}
```

or input any other style.